# PhoneGap iOS7 camera undefined

Tags: cordova, ios7, camera

Seems like I've taken all the steps and measures but cant get iphone camera to work.

1. Include `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`
2. install the plugin: `$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera`
3. Configure config.xml:

3) Call it on deviceready

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady() { alert(navigator.camera) }
```

**returns undefined**

Any suggestions?

I tried it in Ripple and it actually works...

Comment: If it works in Ripple, where did you try it that it didn't work?

Comment: after installing plugin did you run `cordova prepare ios` or `cordova build`?

Comment: I got it thank you! I am using Ionic framework and they suggest using "ionic platform ios" to compile apps but I used "cordova build ios" and it all worked!